# Hive Shell hangs and becomes unresponsive

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-quickstart-vm

My Hive shell hangs at logging initialization at configuration

```
[cloudera@quickstart hive]$ hive
2017-03-01 08:23:50,909 WARN  [main] mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil: The hbase-prefix-tree module jar containing PrefixTreeCodec is not present.  Continuing without it.

Logging initialized using configuration in file:/etc/hive/conf.dist/hive-log4j.properties
```

This is the log file description.

> 2017-02-28 08:56:34,685 WARN  [main]: hive.metastore
>   (HiveMetaStoreClient.java:open(448)) - set_ugi() not successful,
>   Likely cause: new client talking to old server. Continuing without it.
>   org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException:
>   java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out   at
>   org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:129)
>     at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)

Comment: So your MetaStore service is unusable. Tough. Do you have a specific question?

Comment: yes how to get back metasore if the problem is with metstore service?

Comment: I would start by looking at the logs from MetaStore service, to understand what is happening...

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem when I started hive cli. I tried to find [some ways](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/1201/hive-cli-unresponsive.html) to solve the problem, but it didn't work. When I changed the metastore's version (for example, mysql8 to mysql5.6, hive version is 1.10 and don't change) , the problem has been solved!!!!

the log file has already said `new client talking to old server`. So you should change your metastore's version to a new one. It should be kept in mind that your metastore's version match hive's version.